# Advice on how best to approach three quandaries using closures/composition

Tags: javascript

Context
In my quest to improve my JavaScript skillset; I've begun reading an enlightening book called Functional Javascript by Michael Fogus. The 1st chapter has already stretched me far beyond my current proficiency.

Below is my first attempt at closures and scope chain. Frustratingly the below has taken me north of 5 hours to get working.

I'd love to understand and learn from individuals who have a more excellent grasp than me, regarding:

1. Using the scope closure chain - ostensibly is the last return function always this complex; with almost the entire workings encapsulated here? Or am I missing a trick?
2. What is the best way to abstract/compose a means of cleaning up all of the return/console.log outputs into a clean display function, templates or method - apologies I am not sure how best to express that question.
3. What is the cleanest way of sharing findMin between the two f's? Whilst maintaining the composition? The i in i*(a*m)/m needs to move depending on which formula is required. Literally i*(a*m)/m or r*(i*m)/m.

```
function dash(formula) {
    let m = 1000;
    let target = 25;
    return function(rate) {
        return function(numAds) {
            let i = 0;
            onTarget = () => (rate*(numAds*m)/m)>target; 
            findMin  = () => { 
                while ((i*(numAds*m)/m)<target) {
                    i += 0.01;
                }
                return `Corrected Using: ${i.toFixed(2)} Now: ${(i*(numAds*m)/m).toFixed(2)}`;
            };
            if (formula=='cpm') {
                return (onTarget()) ? `Perfect First Time: ${(rate*(numAds*m)/m).toFixed(2)}` : findMin(i);
            } else if (formula=='ad') {
                return (onTarget()) ? `Perfect First Time: ${(rate*(numAds*m)/m).toFixed(2)}` : findMin(i);
            };
        };
    };
};
let cpm = dash('cpm')(1.00)(7);
console.log(cpm);
let ads = dash('ad')(2.30)(13);
console.log(ads);
```

Whilst not addressing the three questions, I have acknowledged two suggestions notably i) using toFixed ii) making my formula elements more meangingful.

Comment: Personally, I'd eliminate `twoDec` and just call `toFixed(2)` directly. You don't have to make every operation into a curried function.

Comment: Please use more descriptive identifiers than `f`, `v`, `r`, `a` - while functional programming is generally quite terse, that doesn't extend to business/domain identifiers., As it is, I have no idea what your program is actually meant to accomplish. (Something to do with online advertising? If so, it's only because I recognise the terms "cpm" and "ad").

Comment: I don't feel `r*(a*m)/m` is readable or maintainable because hardly anyone has the exact JavaScript arithmetic operator precedence rules memorized. Is it meant to be `r * ( ( a* m ) / m )` or `( r * ( a * m ) ) / m`? In any event, the `m` divisor seems redundant as it's cancelled-out by the `m` in the dividend.

Comment: @Dai I've edited the script to revise the formula elements to be more readable. I hope this helps. Essentially they recalculate how much money will be made per 1,000; if it is below the target, then it runs a while loop to find the minimum amount.